# is this convex inequality possibly true?

Tags: inequality, convex-analysis

Let $a_1,\dots,a_k$ be non-negative and sum to $1$ and let $x_1,y_1,\dots,x_k,y_k$ be positive. Then is it true that $$\prod_{i=1}^kx_i^{\alpha_i}+\prod_{i=1}^ky_i^{\alpha_i}\leq\sum_{i=1}^k(x_i+y_i)^{\alpha_i}?$$

This is example $1.2.3$ in Convex Analysis and Minimization Algorithms $I$ by Hiriart-Urruty and Lemarachal.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you suspect it is false or are you looking for a proof? I think this question could do with more context.

Comment: Suspect falsity.

Comment: Why? You are more likely to get helpful answers if you show the reason you think it is false in the question

Comment: $k=2$ and $x_1=x_2=y_1=y_2>2=\frac1{\alpha_1}=\frac1{\alpha_2}$.

Comment: say $k=2$ and $\alpha_1=\alpha_2=\frac12$ and $x_1=x_2=y_1=y_2=r$. As $r\to\infty$, the left hand side is $2r$, while the right hand side is $2^{3/2}r^{1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what happens when all the $x_i$'s and $y_i$'s equal some value $x$ and the $\alpha_i$'s equal $1/k$. Then the claim is that
$$
2x=2\prod_{i=1}^kx^{1/k}\leqslant \sum_{i=1}^k(2x)^{1/k}=k(2x)^{1/k}.
$$

But if $x>(2^{1/k - 1} k)^{1/(1 - 1/k)}$ this is false.